# How to Update a MYSQL Column Based On Varying Conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I need to update a MYSQL Table

Here is a very simple look at Table_A

```
ID  VALUE  RESULT
1   4      0
2   2      0
3   7      0
```

I want to update the RESULT Column based on conditions

So my query statement needs to look something like

```
UPDATE Tabel_A
SET RESULT = (if some condition) 1
             OR (if another condition) 2
             OR (if a different condition) 3
```

Or should I use something like

```
UPDATE Tabel_A
SET RESULT = (CASE 1) 1
             (CASE 2) 2
             (CASE 3) 3
```

I am not sure how to structure the query

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll prefer to use `CASE` here.

```
UPDATE TAble1
SET Result = CASE value
                WHEN 1 THEN x
                WHEN 2 THEN y
                ....
                ELSE z
            END
```

or

```
UPDATE TAble1
SET Result = CASE 
                WHEN value = 1 THEN x
                WHEN value = 2 THEN y
                ....
                ELSE z
            END
```

Comment: Thanks (again) @JW... I was thinking `CASE` would be a good way to go. I am going to incorporate that back into my query and post back later.